# QTP 10 in XP and QTP 11 in win7 is identifying same object with different hierarchy

Tags: qtp

QTP 10 in XP is identifying a webelement as Browser->Page->Viewlink->Webtable->Webelement.

But QTP 11 in win 7 is identifying the same object as Browser->Page->Webtable->Webelement.

It is a tabstrip element, but qtp 11 is identifying the entire table as a single webelement, instead of a specific webelement in the webtable. We are using IE8 in both sytems. Do we need to modify any IE or QTP settings?

Comment: Can you add a link to a site that exhibits this behaviour or some sample HTML?

Comment: Hi i have uploaded copy of Object spy from both versions in http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/558801/ViewLink-docx.html